# Configure exim to use remote smtp with authentication

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, exim

I have a dedicated server with exim on it. I also have a regular shared hosting account ("sharedhostingdomain.com") on hostgator. I want to configure exim to always use hostgator's smtp server ("mail.sharedhostingdomain.com") for email delivery.

The problem is that hostgator's smtp server is obviously requiring authentication and it's on a different port (26). Since I do have legitimate account, I do have access credentials, but I don't know how to force exim to always use that SMTP server instead of trying to connect to the receipient's smtp server directly and where to specify those access credentials.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel says, you need to configure exim as a smarthost. This means defining a router like this (*N.B. the double colon separating the hostname and the port number*):

```
send_to_smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * smarthost.example.com::26
  host_find_failed = defer
  no_more
```

and then a transport that can prod exim into authentication:

```
remote_smtp_smarthost:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp_smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
  hosts_require_auth = smarthost.example.com
```

For a lot of distributions, you can now just put your `host:username:password` triplet into `/etc/exim/passwd.client` and this should just work.

I believe that instead of specifying the port in the router, you can use the `port` command in the transport. In theory, both should work.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've done anything interested with exim configs, but I can give you some basic pointers.  This will also depend on which version of exim you are running, and which distro as well (eg, debian has a meta-config configuration file, which abstracts a lot of this for you).

Basically, you'll want to configure exim with a smarthost, set to hostgator's SMTP server. (This used to be called a "router" in exim-talk, I think it still is).

The transport that your router is configured with will need to be told to use port 26, not port 25. (There is a "port" variable you can set)

You'll also need to setup exim client authentication (eg, check [here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch33.html) for the bit on "Authentication by an exim client"

Sorry I can't be more specific than that, but hopefully this is enough to get you on your way.